# How to set a div data attributes with javascript if the dataset name has more than one dash?

Tags: javascript, html, dataset

I need to update a div layer's dataset with javascript. The below code is working if the dataset has one dash e.g. `data-myvar`...

```
<div id="myDiv" data-myvar="10">

var theDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
theDiv.className = 'newClass';
theDiv.dataset.myvar  = '20';
theDiv.appendChild(content);
```

gives the result

```
<div id="myDiv" data-myvar="20" class="newClass">
```

works great, but when I have a dataset such as `data-myvar-list` it doesn't work. I have tried for example

```
theDiv.dataset.myvar.list  = '20';
```

And this which gives a syntex error

```
theDiv.dataset.myvar-list  = '20';
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You could also use `theDiv.dataset.myvarList` , the dash gets replaced by camel-case.

> dash-style to camelCase: A custom data attribute name is transformed to a key for the DOMStringMap entry with the following rules
>
> - the prefix data- is removed (including the dash);
> - **for any dash (U+002D) followed by an ASCII lowercase letter a to z, the dash is removed and the letter is transformed into its uppercase counterpart;**
> - other characters (including other dashes) are left unchanged.

You can read more about it here --> [source - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#Name_conversion)

**Check out the following snippet**

```js
var theDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
theDiv.className = 'newClass';
console.log(theDiv.dataset.myvarList);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" data-myvar-list="20" class="newClass">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the setAttribute() function to accomplish this:

```
theDiv.setAttribute('data-myvar-list','20');
```

but you might better consider not using the dash and just go with the dataset()

dataset is a native property of an element that contains the data attributes, it's a new(ish) addition and as such is only supported in IE11+, Chrome 8+, FF 6+ etc.

According to this JsPerf

https://jsperf.com/html5-dataset-vs-native-setattribute

The setattribute() method is actually faster by about 25%.